# How can i get the position of a custom listview in these two methods?

Tags: android-listview, swipe-gesture

```js
SwipeListViewTouchListener touchListener = new SwipeListViewTouchListener(listview, new SwipeListViewTouchListener.OnSwipeCallback() {
    private int position;

    @
    Override
    public void onSwipeLeft(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
        String telefonoempresa = choferes.get(position).getTelefonoempresa();
        if (telefonoempresa.contains("----------")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TELEFONO NO DISPONIBLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RED LAR" + telefonoempresa, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + telefonoempresa));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    @
    Override
    public void onSwipeRight(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {

        String telefonoparticular = choferes.get(position).getTelefonoparticular();
        if (telefonoparticular.contains("----------")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TELEFONO NO DISPONIBLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TELEFONO PARTICULAR" + telefonoparticular, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + telefonoparticular));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}, true, false);

listview.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Think you must style your question a little better :) The first part is unreadable, and dont know where to start to correct it.

Comment: Sorry, the first part was just to explain that my listview uses images and text, the two methods above it are made to make phone calls depending if you slide your finger to the right or to the left, my problem is that those methods doesn't get the position in which you slide your finger. Instead of doing that the methods always call to the first phone number of my array list.

Comment: Thats OK. Have tried to correct syntax highlightning/beutify the code. But what is your question? Try to explain / elaborate in depth.

Comment: I want to know how to add the parameter "position" in both methods to get the position of the item you slide in the listview.

Comment: Put that in your question above. You can, of course, edit your own question.

Comment: I don't know how to make the question even clearer, i guess i need to keep reading about this sliding custom listview issue, but thanks for your help.

Comment: There is an edit-button. You can edit your own question. Edit your comments into the question. Try to set yourself in the opposit situation, would you be able to answer a headline / piece of code like that? And how should it benefit other stackoverflow users?

Comment: I know i can edit it, and i already did it, i've simplified it as possible thinking as if i was the person who reads this, maybe is a complicated topic for beginner and experienced programmers.